# Реализация класса

Tags: c++, классы

Помогите реализовать данный класс:

```
class Car {
private:
    std::string marka_;
    unsigned int mskorost_;
    unsigned int emkost_;
public:
    Car()
    {
        marka_ = "";
        mskorost_ = 1800;
        emkost_ = 1800;
    }

    Car(const std::string &marka, unsigned int mskorost, unsigned int emkost)
    {
        marka_ = marka;
        mskorost_ = mskorost;
        emkost_ = emkost;
    }

    virtual ~Car()
    {}

    void setMarka(const std::string &marka)
    {
        marka_= marka;
    }

    std::string getMarka() const
    {
        return marka_;
    }
```

Необходимо реализовать следующие операции: ввод и вывод списка, добавление и удаление элементов, поиск элементов по ключу.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: так в чём собственно проблема ? для реализации этих операций заведите ещё список машин например в виде `std::map<>` в классе и делайте все эти операции - если что то не получится пишите

Comment: Думаю что в задании имелось ввиду показать работу с STL контейнерами...